# How to play list of youtube videos in iframe

Tags: c#, .net, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I have different YouTube video id's to play in iframe, at present only one video playing at a time, for handling next video i tried onPlayerStateChange() event, but event not fires when video is ended, is there any way to fire an event when video is ended or play multiple video one after another. any one please help me.

i have tried this below code.

html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ifplayer_onPlayerStateChange() {
            alert("statechanged");
        }
</script>
<iframe id="ifplayer" runat="server"/>
```

cs code:

```
ifplayer.Attributes.Add("src", "//www.youtube.com/embed/videoid");
ifplayer.Attributes.Add("onload", "ifplayer_onPlayerStateChange();");
```

Comment: Why you need an `iframe` if it is possible without `iframe` as well.

Comment: how can we please suggest me..

Comment: You have already marked an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tired this below code to play another video after first video ended, it's working for me.

```
<iframe class="ytplayer" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwfnT4CKoJo?enablejsapi=1" id="player" height="500" width="600" runat="server"></iframe>

<script>
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player( 'player', {
            events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange },            
        });
      }
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        switch(event.data) {
            case 0:               
                    document.getElementById('player').src = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhGQSsuTjmw?enablejsapi=1";
                    onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();                           
            break;
          case 1:
              alert('video playing from ' + player.getCurrentTime());
            break;
          case 2:
              alert('video paused at ' + player.getCurrentTime
            break;
        }
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at the YouTube API First and see if that can take away some of the work you need to do as google might have already created a solution to that.

You can find it here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/code_samples

Comment: there will be a lot, please provide me the exact url..thankyou